# How to extract value inside with statement?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to initialize variable in pl/sql In the following way. But the value of the variable is null. how can I modify this code?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_TEMP
(
    pList0 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
    TEMP_COL1 VARCHAR2(100);
    TEMP_COL2 VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

    OPEN cv_1 FOR                
         WITH TEMP_TABLE(COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2 ,...., COLUMN_N) 
         AS (SELECT COL_1, COL_2, ... , COL_N)

         SELECT COL_1, COL_2
         INTO TEMP_COL1, TEMP_COL2
         FROM TEMP_TABLE;


         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TEMP_COL1);     -- null!!
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TEMP_COL2);     -- null!!

END;
```

Comment: What do you want your procedure to do actually? Open a cursor and return it? Or read the values itself? Which row's values are you trying to show? The first row's? Or do you want a loop and show all values? Do you want your procedure to fetch all the data and show its values and then also return the cursor, so the caller can again loop through it?

Comment: OPEN cursor statements cannot include INTO clause in its SELECT. You procedure cannot compile without error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't open a cursor; just use the `SELECT`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_TEMP
(
    pList0 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
  TEMP_COL1 VARCHAR2(100);
  TEMP_COL2 VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   WITH TEMP_TABLE(COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2 ,...., COLUMN_N) AS (
     SELECT COL_1, COL_2, ... , COL_N
     FROM your_table -- Need to select from a table.
   )
   SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2 -- Use the aliases you set in the sub-query factoring clause.
   INTO   TEMP_COL1, TEMP_COL2
   FROM   TEMP_TABLE
   WHERE  ROWNUM = 1 -- Only want a single row returned into the variables;

   -- Or simpler
   SELECT COL_1, COL_2
   INTO   TEMP_COL1, TEMP_COL2
   FROM   your_table
   WHERE  ROWNUM = 1 -- Only want a single row returned into the variables;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TEMP_COL1);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TEMP_COL2);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `FETCH` loop from the cursor. The easiest way to do this to use an implicit cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_TEMP AS
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN
  (
    WITH temp_table(column_1, column_2 ,...., column_n) AS
      (SELECT col_1, col_2, ... , col_n)
    SELECT col_1, col_2
    FROM temp_table
  ) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.col1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.col2);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If, on the other hand, you only want to return the opened cursor, then you must not fetch from it yourself.

If you want to do both, i.e. fetch data yourself and return the cursor, then you must open the cursor twice for the same query. Once to process it yourself, once to give it to the caller to process it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_TEMP
(
  out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
  v_col1 VARCHAR2(100);
  v_col2 VARCHAR2(100);
  v_sql VARCHAR2(1000) := 'WITH temp_table ... SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM temp_table';
BEGIN
  OPEN out_cursor FOR v_sql;

  LOOP
    FETCH out_cursor INTO v_col1, v_col2;
    EXIT WHEN out_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_1: ' || v_col1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_2: ' || v_col2);
  END LOOP;

  OPEN out_cursor FOR v_sql;
END;
```